# Groupfield not showing in grid exjts

Tags: extjs

Groupfield not showing in grid exjts.

In my grid i am using groupfield: 'project', this one is grouping properly, but i want to show the column 'project in my grid default with out check the column field checkbox'.

Can you please help me on this.

In my grid i am using groupfield: 'project', this one is grouping properly, but i want to show the column 'project in my grid default with out check the column field checkbox'.

Please find the below fiddle link:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3pi4&view/editor

Comment: Do you want the column `project` to be visible for every row (meaning that the same column value will be repeated for all rows in the current group)?

Comment: Yes the Project column need to visible is default in grid

Comment: But your fiddle shows the Project column now, doesn't it?